# how to convert jquery post values to array

Tags: php, pdo

post values from jquery are (id_workers: 1124,1545,4268)

```
$rows= array($_POST['id_workers']);
foreach($rows as $row) { 
   echo $row;// has to echo 112415454268
                but its show 1124,1545,4268
}

// sample code workers perfectly
$rows= array(1124,1545,4268);
foreach($rows as $row) { 
    echo $row;// result 112415454268
}
```

unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: You are displaying them without a game - so why are you surprised of the result?

Try:
`echo $row + ",";`

Comment: `$rows= array($_POST['id_workers']);` That's creating an array with one element `1124,1545,4268`

Comment: You probably meant `$rows = explode(‘,’, $_POST['id_workers']);`.

Comment: tried echo $row + ","; but same.

Comment: @JCode I don't think that's how concatenation works in PHP. I recommend brushing up on stuff like that before trying to correct people.

Comment: $rows = $_POST['id_workers'];// echo 1124,1545,4268
$data = 1124,1545,4268;  // echo 112415454268  i tested manually but the result varies

Comment: i just want to insert into multiple rows using PDO foreach statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `1124,1545,4268` because `$_POST['id_workers']` having string value comma separated like `"1124,1545,4268"`.

When you try to use `array("1124,1545,4268")` it will use only 1 index like:

```
Array ( [0] => 1124,1545,4268 )
```

So, you need to use `explode()` here to convert string into an array like:

```
$rows= explode(",",$_POST['id_workers']);

foreach($rows as $row) { 
    echo $row; // 112415454268          
}
```

If comma is an issue **only**, you can also use `str_replace()` to remove comma from a string like:

```
$rows = $_POST['id_workers'];
echo str_replace(",", "", $rows); // 112415454268
```